# Apex triggers to interact with sql server

Tags: apex, webservices, security, soap, sqlserver

We are in the beginning stages of getting set up in Salesforce, and there is something that I am having a little trouble getting my head wrapped around;

We currently have a local SQL server relational database, and the main table is our customer table. The customer table ID is the main foreign key for a lot of other tables.
During this initial phase, and possibly beyond, we will have to maintain customers in both the Salesforce system and locally.
That's fine for all existing customers, as I understand that it's not that hard to move data from the SQL server to Salesforce. But if we create a new customer in Salesforce then they won't exist locally, and more importantly won't have a valid customer ID.

I've been learning about SOAP web services, and those things, but I'm having trouble with some of the concepts, and security really concerns me.

What are the best, most cost-effective ways to do something like this?

Comment: Setup some kind of an API next to your SQL server (e.g. a basic C# crud one), write an Apex trigger for `after insert` and an HTTP callout to that API. When a new 'customer' record is created in SF, SF will call your API and tell you about it. This will only work well when just a handful of records are created. If you frequently create a lot of data (either side) you will need to setup some sync job (e.g. download/upload every 5 mins or so). Recently SF added a lot of API calls so i would write that outside of SF using their REST API.

Comment: "Best" and "cost-effective" are opinion-based terms - your best may not be someone else's best, please see [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more info. Have a look at [Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm) for an overview of your options

Answer (score 1):

For a no code approach on the Salesforce side and scalability, consider using [Outbound Messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm). When you database operations happen on a customer record in Salesforce, have an outbound message be sent on creation/updates. The outbound message can be sent to an endpoint that is connected to your SQL server to create the customer there as well. An outbound message can contain a session id so your SQL server can make a callback to Salesforce with a valid customer ID once the customer record is created in your SQL server. Be sure to save the customer ID on a unique external id field for each customer record you create in Salesforce.

You can also go the apex trigger route, but that will require more maintenance.

For your security concerns, read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_security.htm). You can use a [certificate](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_about.htm&type=5) to make sure your SQL server is indeed receiving requests that are legitimate.

Comment: That is some useful information. Thanks! Right now I'm mostly at the point where I don't know enough to even know what questions to ask, and so I'm trying to fit it in the frameworks I already know, like linked servers and such, but that's kind of a silly state of mind to be in. Better to try to understand the new "right" way to do things.